# Need SQL query to get latest chat message between me and each my contact when my contact list is displayed

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-relations

I have the below tables in the database.

Users

- id
- name
- email
- created_at
- updated_at

Contacts

- id
- user_id (foreign key to users table)
- contact_id (foreign key to users table)
- created_at
- updated_at

Messages

- id
- sender_id  (foreign key to users table)
- receiver_id (foreign key to users table)
- message
- created_at
- updated_at

All I want is to display my contact list along with latest chat message which happend between me and my each contact whether I am sender or receiver in that message.

Expecting below result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Contact Name | Latest Message |Message Time (messages.created_at)|
----------------------------------------------------------------
| John Doe        | Hello there      | 2023-03-09 03:17:55
| Martin          | Hi Martin        | 2023-03-08 12:20:10
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Are you expecting a SQL or Laravel answer?

Comment: I am using MySQL as Database, Laravel relation would be better but I can go with custom SQL query as well, Thanks for your response, really appreciate

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: This one:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.27-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: above version, I get using **mysql -V** command in the terminal but my MySQL client **(Adminer)** is showing **"MySQL version: 10.4.27-MariaDB through PHP extension MySQLi"**, I don't know why there is a difference, I use **Adminer** to create and manage Databases